# Wondering if there is a way to find the code related to rendering of a <div>

Tags: html, typescript

I am a new employee and I've been tasked to create a chart similar to one that is already on their website. I know how to create it, but I cannot find the place in the code where the other chart is rendered(i.e. render() ), is there any way I can find it with the help of the browser? or do I have to simply search for it manually in the source code? The website is using typescript.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question. Good luck 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use hit and trial method.

1. Open the website page where the chart is showing in Chrome.
2. Open developer console ( In Windows Chrome press ctrl+shift+i or F12).
3. Hover over the chart using the inspect button(ctrl+shift+c). In elements tab you will see the specific div for that chart.

From that point on you have to find the div, ids, css and scripts related to the Chart.